# Setting Proxy IP and Port in android code?

Tags: android, proxy

Is there any way to add Proxy IP and Port in android application so that the internet access will be routed through the Proxy?

From a link i got the information

try {
                    Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:100");//enable proxy
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }

But by trying this System variable cannot be resolved?

Please help!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to add a proxy for web access via a browser? Why would your app want to change the browser proxy?

Comment: Hi, my application should also work with proxy server.Android device 2.3.4 directly has no options for setting Proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection con =null;

URL url = new URL("xxxxx");

Proxy proxy=new Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost(),android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort()));

con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Is this okay?